# Existence of Solutions of Two Cubic Equations in a Particular Region

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

If I have two cubic equations in two variables, $ax^3 + bx^2 y + cxy^2+\dots=0$ and another one with different coefficients, and I know that $(x,y)=(0,0)$ or $(1,1)$ are solutions, are there any nice, explicitly computable conditions on the parameters that would guarantee the existence of another solution $(x,y) \in (0,1)^2$? And is there any way to factor out roots like in the single-variable case?

Comment: unlikely. To factor out roots, you need to know the set of solutions, e.g. if you know that $x=y$ are solutions, then you know that $x-y$ is a factor. Even if you know that $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are roots, they might belong to different factors/families.

Comment: Are there still possible conditions on the coefficients that would guarantee a solution in the prescribed range, or is that also unlikely?

Comment: Sean, welcome to MSE! On stackexchange if you want somebody to receive a notification of your comment you have to write @CalvinLin , or else he won't be notified. The reason you were notified now of my comment is because I am commenting on your own question. It would work the same way if I commented on an answer of yours.

Comment: Ovi I did get informed of his comment (and yours), because I'm part of this thread. I'm not certain about the exact notification procedure; [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) seems to be a detailed writeup. Thanks for helping out new MSE users :)